# Visual Studio Code: Initial VueJS setup cannot find module "@/.."

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, vetur

As you know `@` is a placeholder for `/src` and the application compiles and runs properly if I use it so. But my VSCode thinks the module is not there and show me an error message:

[image: Visual Studio Code: cannot find module]

**Question 1: How can I teach VSCode how to find the modules?**

A similar situation is the following:

```
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;
}
```

There are two errors in the IDE (while the application compiles and runs properly):

1) `!:` is red underlined -> *Expression expected*

[image]

2) `string` is red underlined -> *Member 'string' implicitly has an 'any' type.*

[image]

But these are not really errors, that's the normal syntax and VSCode cannot deal with it. Vetur Extension (Vue Tooling for VSCode) is already installed.

**Question 2: How can I deal with Vue + TypeScript in VSCode at all? What (all) do I have to consider?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Importing `*.svg`

VS Code doesn't know how to import an `svg` file on its own. To fix this, add a `.d.ts` file to the root of your project, containing:

```js
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

I found that adding this declaration to `src/shims.d.ts` does not work. It only worked when creating a `.d.ts` file at the project root (e.g., `<root>/index.d.ts`).

### `Expression expected` error

That's from Vetur 0.11.7, which uses an older TypeScript version that doesn't support [definite assignment assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions), introduced in TypeScript 2.7. ([`vuejs/vetur` Issue #723](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/723))

<del>Vetur `0.11.8 Preview` fixes the issue by updating to the newer version of TypeScript, but this is not yet released, so you'll have to [install the VSIX manually](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_install-from-a-vsix). The simplest method IMO is to use the command drop-down from VS Code's *Extensions* view to install the downloaded [`vetur-0.11.8.vsix`](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/releases/download/0.11.8/vetur-0.11.8.vsix).</del> **The fix is available in Vetur [`0.12.1`](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/releases/tag/0.12.1), which is installable from VS Code's *Extensions* view.**